# Removing rows below first line that meets threshold in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a df that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'Hours':np.arange(12, 97, 12),
     'Average':np.random.random(8),
     'Count':[500, 250, 125, 75, 60, 25, 5, 15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

This df has a decrease number of cases for each row. After the count drops below a certain threshold, I'd like to drop off the remainder, for example after a < 10 case threshold was reached.

Starting:

```
    Average     Count   Hours
0   0.560671    500     12
1   0.743811    250     24
2   0.953704    125     36
3   0.313850    75      48
4   0.640588    60      60
5   0.591149    25      72
6   0.302894    5       84
7   0.418912    15      96
```

Finished (everything after row 6 removed):

```
    Average     Count   Hours
0   0.560671    500     12
1   0.743811    250     24
2   0.953704    125     36
3   0.313850    75      48
4   0.640588    60      60
5   0.591149    25      72
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the index generated from the boolean index and slice the df using `iloc`:

```
In [58]:

df.iloc[:df[df.Count < 10].index[0]]
Out[58]:
    Average  Count  Hours
0  0.183016    500     12
1  0.046221    250     24
2  0.687945    125     36
3  0.387634     75     48
4  0.167491     60     60
5  0.660325     25     72
```

Just to break down what is happening here

```
In [54]:
# use a boolean mask to index into the df
df[df.Count < 10]
Out[54]:
    Average  Count  Hours
6  0.244839      5     84

In [56]:
# we want the index and can subscript the first element using [0]
df[df.Count < 10].index
Out[56]:
Int64Index([6], dtype='int64')
```